# Equilibrium Problem Involving Solids: Faulty?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium

I am convinced that this is a faulty problem:

> $\ce{2 Cu + S -> Cu2S}$
>
> For the reaction above, $\Delta H$, $\Delta S$, and $\Delta G$ are all negative. Which of the substances would predominate in an equilibrium mixture of copper, sulfur, and copper(I) sulfide at $298~\mathrm{K}$?  Explain how you drew your conclusions...

The problem as written does not include state symbols, but they are obviously all in the solid states. However, *solids don't achieve equilibrium*, at least as far as I know. Thus, how can one talk of an "equilibrium mixture" of solids?

Update:

How can I explain the fact that using the ubiquitous equation $\Delta G^{\circ} = -RT\ln K$, I do indeed get an equilibrium constant?

Comment: I think it’s a trick question. At $298~\mathrm{K}$ it should take longer than the age of the universe for $\ce{2Cu + S <=>> Cu2S}$ to reach equilibrium …

Comment: Why, solids **do** achieve equilibrium, it's just that it happens to be shifted all the way to one side.